# How to call resource route Codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Please I need help to enable me know how to map the resource route to http request.

for example am trying to call this url via axios

http://localhost/nmc/public/api/unregisteredpatients?userid=hen11@gmail.com

and i have created the following resource routes to call my api

```
//$routes->resource('api/unregisteredpatients/(:any)', 'UnregisteredPatients::show/$1', ['namespace' => 'Api']);
//$routes->get('api/unregisteredpatients/(:any)', 'UnregisteredPatients::show/$1', ['namespace' => 'Api']);
$routes->resource('api/unregisteredpatients/(:any)', ['controller' => 'Api/UnregisteredPatients']);
```

None of these was able to call my api method instead they all called the index() method, whereas I wanted it to call the show($id) method to enable me utilise the $id to fetch data.

```
public function show($id = null) {
  .....
}
```

Please I need help

Answer (score 0):

This solves it for me, though I couldn't have a way to capture query parameters but passing the parameter as a segment gives me an AFAIK solution.

```
$routes->match(['get'], 'api/unregisteredpatients/(:any)', 'Api\UnregisteredPatients::show/$1');
```